# GUI Emoji Selector for Debian 11

Tags: debian, gui, emoji

On Debian 11, which package can I install that will provide a GUI for Emoji selection?

I'm looking for a package that:

- Has **minimal dependencies**
- Works across **multiple desktop environments / window managers**

I want to avoid packages that require the installation of an entire desktop environment in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you search for (it depends on Gnome), but [the extension Emoji Selector](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1162/emoji-selector/) is doing a great job:

[image: Gnome emoji picker]